# Is it possible to completely dispose of a usercontrol in winrt?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I have an app where I dynamically create user controls depending on the situation.  When I'm done with them I remove them from the container, but they are still taking up memory.

I've implemented a "dispose" method in the code to clear the controls inside of the user control, but I still feel like there is a better way to do it.

I'm not sure what code I can post as no code is really relevant.

All I really have is what I'm doing now with the dispose method

```
  public void Dispose()
        {

            ContentWebView.NavigateToString("about:blank");
            YoutubeMediaPlayer.Stop();
        }
```

Comment: just seen similar issue on MS connect, they say it's by design: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/772386/winrt-memory-leak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Dispose` method is used for releasing *unmanaged* resources.

When all references to an object are removed, the garbage collector will eventually "Collect" it (freeing the memory). You can't actually control when this happens, even calling `GC.Collect` is technically just a suggestion. You can, however, invoke dispose on an object directly (note that this may cause odd behavior or exceptions if it is still in use!)

If you suspect a control has unmanaged resources that need to be cleaned up, you should call `Dispose` on it directly when you are finished with it (GDI Bitmap objects need to be cleaned up like this). From your comments, it sounds like you just need the garbage collector to actually free the memory, which is something thats hard to control (you can try calling `GC.Collect` though).

MSDN for Dispose: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx

Comment: That's the problem.  Usercontrols don't implement iDiposable by default. It's left up to me to write my own.  Webview also doesn't implement iDisposable, which is why I navigate to blank.  That actually does a good job of unloading any content loaded into the webview.  I have a youtube player that will continue playing aver all references are removed.  Which is why I stop it on dispose.  So far what I have is the best I could come up with.  I definitely can't remove it as it's the only thing clearing memory at the moment.

Comment: Ok, so you stop it. Can you call `Dispose` on it? It sounds like you are doing everything you can to free up memory, and just need the collector to actually collect it (as my answer kind of indicated). Am I missing the thrust of your question?

Comment: Slight clarification: The GC doesn't "call `Dispose` on everything".

Comment: Oh! Huh, I tried disposing the webview, but never tried with the media player.  And yes, I can dispose it. It works perfectly.  I think you got the thrust of my question and your links are helpful.  I just wasn't sure if I was doing all I could.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET You should remove the "GC calls `Dispose` on everything" statement. It does not. (directly tagged you in this so you get a notification)

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, Sorry I didn't get this edit in earlier, fixed! Thank you so much for the feedback.